# How to set unit_price automatically as I select product in odoo 15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I have made one model which is listed below, I want to set the price automatically as I select the product.

```
class JobCardLine(models.Model):
    _name = "job.card.line"

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string="Product", tracking=True)    
    price = fields.Many2one('product.template.',string="Price", tracking=True)
```

I think it can be done using depends on onchange but not able to do that.

Comment: `price = fields.Float(string="Price", related='product_id.lst_price')`
replace the price field with the above
why price is Many2one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [on_change](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.api.onchange) to automatically set the price to the product `list_price`

***Example:***

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def _change_price(self):
    self.price = self.product_id.list_price
```

*You will need to change the `price` field type to `Float`*

You can do it using a computed field but you will need to implement the [inverse function](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#computed-fields) to allow setting values on the field and the unit price should depend on product price